# zabbix - passing result of one item into the URL for a second item

Tags: http, zabbix

I'm currently using `Zabbix 5.0`. I have a monitoring item of type `HTTP Agent` set up that calls a `REST API` to retieve an item of data.

Is there a way to pass the result of that first item into the string for a second item?

e.g.

```
item 1 + pre-processing:
http://{username}:{password}@10.1.2.3:8443/api/metadata/
```

retrieves the value `12345` with a name of `Server_ID`

can I then use that `Server_ID` value in the second one?

e.g.

```
item2
http://{username}:{password}@10.1.2.3:8443/api/metadata/{Server_ID}/status
```

These would both be part of the same template.

I've seen there are `type:dependent` items but that seems to be for retrieving multiple pieces of data from the first item only.
I've also seen there is something about `type:scripts` in 5.4 that may be what I want, but I don't know how long it will be before we upgrade to that version.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.

There are only [some macros you can use](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/http) in the URL field:

> **Supported macros:** {HOST.IP}, {HOST.CONN}, {HOST.DNS}, {HOST.HOST}, {HOST.NAME}, {ITEM.ID}, {ITEM.KEY}, user macros, low-level discovery macros.

That's it.

I haven't tried it, but the `low-level discovery macros` sound interesting. If the server ID you get with your first check is constant for the server, you could turn your check into a [discovery rule](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/configuration/hosts/discovery) that creates the actual check. You can use the same prepocessing steps there and it should allow you to use the ID in the actual check.

Comment: The Discovery Rules looks like it could work, if only I could actually make it work. So far it has led to more questions and much head scratching.

Comment: I have similar problem but when trying to use LLD I am getting `Cannot find the "data" array in the received JSON object.`

Comment: @ReddySK why don't you ask a question about it?